# Uploadify errors. Not uploading images.

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am trying to get uploadify to upload but it's returning a few errors:

Here are the errors:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(/home/mydomain/public_html/uploadslogo.png) [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/home/mydomain/public_html/uploadify/uploadify.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
<br />


<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpvoUwxK' to '/home/mydomain/public_html/uploadslogo.png' in <b>/home/domain/public_html/uploadify/uploadify.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
1true
```

And here is the uploadify.php code:

```
<?php

$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the trailing slash after the `uploads` directory. Try:

```
$targetFolder = '/uploads/'; // Relative to the root
```

You'll also want to change:

```
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

To:

```
$targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

Comment: Changed it but still getting the same error: <b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(/home/mydomain/public_html/uploadslogo.png) [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/home/mydomain/public_html/uploadify/uploadify.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />

Comment: The trailing slash is being removed by the following line:
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
Change it to:
$targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];